# How to validate token_id at user endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, openid-connect

I have implemented openid connect on top of oauth2, but now i want to stop token substitution attack as any person get the admin rights if he manage to interpret the admin user response.

To solve my problem what are the points i need to keep into consideration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is very easy to stop token substitution. Validate your tokens. Tokens are signed with a private key and verified with a public key. Very simple to implement and enforce.

If instead you mean to prevent users from substituting (swapping) valid tokens to grant increased privileges, then track who the token is issued to and only accept tokens from that user that were issued to that user. Another method is to create a private / public keypair per user when you create tokens. Then users cannot swap tokens as the public key will be different and the signature validation will fail.

Tokens should have short lifetimes (minutes). When they expire, the tokens are either refreshed or reauthorized. You determine the policy and expiration.

Everything I mentioned is common knowlege on the Internet with a large number of examples in just about all common languages.

Comment: Suppose i am admin user and login though my credentials but forgot to logout, then some intruder comes to my machine and pick the token from let say cookie and paste to his machine and accessing the APIs.

I check i can performed is to check the current session and if match with the user he claims to be.

Do you have any better solution.

Comment: Your client<->server session should be encrypted in transit and at rest. This prevents this problem. Short-lived tokens also help prevent pick-pocketing credentials. However, if your workstation is unprotected, you are in trouble in so many additional ways that are far more serious.

Comment: I am very much curious how substitution token attack being prevented.
1. Suppose i am user1 login to auth server and auth sever grant me token, which i save in local storage to access protected resource apis.
2. Now 2nd user comes and he just copy the jwt token from user1 and now untill token is valid he can access the API without login.

Now how could i prevent, appreciate if you can elaborate

Comment: Please close this question and create a new question. Ping me once you create the question.

Comment: I have posted  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955977/how-to-prevent-token-substitution-attack