# How to prevent token substitution attack?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, access-token, openid-connect

Suppose we have two users doing following operation -

1. User1 requested to the auth server for access token and granted also.
2. Now user1 save the token into localstorage/cookie for future api access.
3. Now User2 approach User1 browswer and get the access_token some how.
4. Now User2 call the api using user1's  access_token and get the access too without login.

Now Can we validate the token anyhow?

Comment: @name John Hanley can you please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid that happening. However, the token should have an expiration time, so the attacker will only have access during that time. Also, if you know that a token has been stolen, you can revoke it so it's no longer valid.

You could apply more security measures such as associating the token with a specific IP address, or some advanced services that even use machine learning to detect unusual behaviours.

Comment: I thought we can manage by managing session on server side and check the incoming token with session token,but then on every request i have to call the user endpoint.

Comment: Before accessing sensitive information, you can also require the user to enter credentials again, e.g. before changing his password.

Comment: Be aware that a client's IP address may change during a session. Especially if it's a mobile client.

Answer (score 0):

Confidential information such as an OAuth Token should never be stored in HTTP Cookies unless encrypted. The encryption should be client / session specific meaning that a different encryption key should be used for each client session. If an intruder were to extract the encrypted cookie and attempt to use it for a different session the decryption would fail rendering the cookie invalid.

In your scenario, User B obtains access to User A's session. There is not much protection available. This would be similar to you logging into your bank, leaving your desk for coffee and someone else sits down and starts transferring money using the same browser window that you logged into.

Security is only as strong as the weakest link. Each component must implement strong security. If a single component can be breached, then the other security components might also fail.

There is a tradeoff between very tight security and convenience. Human beings tend to sacrifice security if the processes are too tedious or too difficult or just plain get in the way.

My bank does something interesting. Once I login and keep doing stuff (clicking links, moving the mouse, etc.) I stay authenticated. If I pause for one minute, then the next time I click a link I must reauthenticate. Interesting strategy to detect a person who might have left his desk unattended.

Comment: using jwt will avoid encrypting and i cant encrypt using client session as i am building a SPA app.

Comment: That makes a difference for SPA. This means that the user is authenticating directly with Google and not via (thru) your website. You have no control over the token and the security of the token lies with the user. The user can only grant themselves access to data that they own / control.

Comment: A JWT is not encrypted. It is signed by the account's Private Key to prevent alteration.

Comment: No i am the one who issue the token, as gbandres suggest, we can add host related information and verify at application end.

Comment: How are you accomplishing this with an SPA? SPAs run in the client's browser, which means that you cannot do anything secret that I could not figure out in a minute or two (e.g. security). If instead you mean that you are using serverless for compute power ...

Comment: Are you implementing your own OAuth instead of using an Identity Provider such as Google?